# SSRS loop over select by months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am creating report in SSRS that should show event duration in a month. This report should do it 12 time for every calendar month separately. At the moment my select has 12 hardcoded selects, for every month each. How can I do this with one select repeated 12 times and just iterated start and end times, either in SQL language (applicable as a view) or even better from SSRS? Thank you.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000', end_date) AS total_event
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE (start_date <= '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND (end_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, start_date, '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000') AS total_event
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE (end_date >= '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000') AND (start_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000') AS total_event
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE (start_date <= '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND (end_date >= '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, start_date, end_date) AS total_event
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE (start_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000') AND (end_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Answer (score 0):

try using below script

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

set @start = '2014-01-01'  --firstDay year
set @end = '2014-12-31'    --last Day of year

;with cte as
(
select @start firstday, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @start), 0))+1,0)) lastday,  1 MM
union all
select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, lastday + 1), 0) , DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, lastday + 1), 0))+1,0)),  MM + 1
from cte
where lastday < @end
)
SELECT * FROM CTE C   
--LEFT OUTER JOIN MY_TABLE M ON (M.start_date <= firstday) AND (end_date BETWEEN firstday AND lastday)
```

just un-comment last line

```
--LEFT OUTER JOIN MY_TABLE M ON (M.start_date <= firstday) AND (end_date BETWEEN firstday AND lastday)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, start_date), 0) AS [month], DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, start_date), 0), end_date) AS total_event
FROM
    MY_TABLE
WHERE
    YEAR(start_date) = 2014
ORDER BY
    [month];
```